# Material UI - Why the background image doesn't scrolls with the scroll bar?

Tags: material-ui, background, frontend

I made a box that extends beyond the bottom margin of the screen, so a scroll bar appeared.
When i scroll down the page, instead of staying in the background, the background image simply rolls up (from my point of view).
This seemed to be a simple problem to solve, then i used
`sx={{backgroundAttachment: 'fixed'}}` and the problem continued.
I sat the backgroundAttachment to scroll and the problem persisted.
I don't have a clue of why it is happening or how to fix it.
My background component:

```
import { Container } from '@mui/material'
import backgroundImage from '../assets/images/BG.jpg'
function BackgroundImage(props) {
  return (
    <Container
      {...props}
      sx={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        minWidth: '100vw',
        border: 'none',
        margin: 'none',
        padding: 'none',
        backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
      }}
/>
  )
}

export default BackgroundImage
```

The page who extends beyond the bottom margin:

```
import { Box } from '@mui/material'

function PostInvite(){
    return(
        <Box sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '854px',
            height: '946px',
            left: '293px',
            top: '289px',
            background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #FD5F6D 0%, #141C27 100%)',
            mixBlendMode: 'luminosity',
            opacity: 0.7,
            boxShadow: '0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
        }}>
            afsfdashdiu
        </Box>
    )
}

export default PostInvite;
```